# php - sorting by points and then alphabetically

Tags: php, sorting

I have an array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
       ( [points] => 10
         [id] => 58
         [nazwa] => auser1 )
    [1] => Array
       ( [points] => 15
         [id] => 36
         [nazwa] => cuser2 )
    [2] => Array 
       ( [points] => 15
         [id] => 57
         [nazwa] => buser3 )
    [3] => Array
       ( [points] => 20
         [id] => 56
         [nazwa] => duser4 )
    [4] => Array
       ( [points] => 20
         [id] => 54
         [nazwa] => euser5 ))
```

I would like to sort this array by `points` and then alphabetically by `nazwa`.

How can I do this?

I would like to create final points table for Russia Cup!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried using any of PHP's sort functions?

Comment: @Michal Izydowicz, did you get the solution?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to sort your multidimensional array in sequence first points then with name then you have to create your multidimensional array in same sequence format 
example: first element should be points, second name, last id. Refer following sequence.

```
 $array = [ [ 'points' => 10, 'nazwa' => 'auser1', 'id' => 58 ],
    [ 'points' => 15, 'nazwa' => 'cuser2', 'id' => 36 ],
    [ 'points' => 15, 'nazwa' => 'buser3', 'id' => 57 ],
    [ 'points' => 20, 'nazwa' => 'duser4', 'id' => 56 ],
    [ 'points' => 20, 'nazwa' => 'euser5', 'id' => 54 ]];

    array_multisort( $array );
    print_r(($array));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [points] => 10
            [nazwa] => auser1
            [id] => 58
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [points] => 15
            [nazwa] => buser3
            [id] => 57
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [points] => 15
            [nazwa] => cuser2
            [id] => 36
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [points] => 20
            [nazwa] => duser4
            [id] => 56
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [points] => 20
            [nazwa] => euser5
            [id] => 54
        )

)
```